# CodeIgniter - sql return only the first letter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a directory for a vocabulary page for a site I'm building. So when you click the A link it will pull back all the letters that start with A and so on. I have most of the functionality done, but I can't get the right sql statement to pull back what I want.

I'm working on this...

```
$this->db->order_by("title", "asc");
$this->db->where('category', 'vocab');
$this->db->like('title', $this->uri->segment(3));
$data['query'] = $this->db->get('entries');
```

So, I've been trying to get the like function working. To match the first letter in the title with the letter I'm throwing in the url when the user clicks on the link.

Any help? Am I doing the like clause right? I've never actually had to do one before.

Comment: %title would be more usefull if you want the first letter. .

Comment: sorry, but I don't think codeigniter allows % signs in where clauses...at least it throws me an error when I try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to change one row:

```
$this->db->like('title', $this->uri->segment(3), 'after');
```

Also, note the way you get results: `$this->db->get('entries')->result();`

Comment: there we go, found it! And thank you again for helping me! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Great, you're welcome! Also welcome aboard, if you have time, please go through the rest of the FAQ as there are some really great things on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both' (which is the default).

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before'); // Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after'); // Produces: WHERE title LIKE 'match%' 
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both'); // Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
```

[You can see the codeIgniter Active Record Page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)